# Is it possible to use an apple TV2 with standar tv (composite)

Tags: appletv, television

The title say it all... Is it possible to use an apple TV2 with standar tv (composite). The apple tv 1, the original have a composite connector, but the tv2 dont. You will ask me to get an HD tv, but i dont watch TV, i like to use it for music only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, according to [Apple](http://www.apple.com/appletv/specs.html), the only connector the new Apple TV has is HDMI, which means, if you want to use it with your TV that doesn't have HDMI input, you'll need an adapter. Just google 'HDMI to composite adapter'

If you only want the *audio*, then .... you'll still probably need an adapter. HDMI cables carry both audio and video so you'll need to convert the signal to something your TV will accept to get any music playing.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The Apple TV 2 outputs digital music from a TOSlink port as well as the combined Video and Sound on HDMI. Although there are some cables that purport to do the transition to RCA / VGA for between $10 and $25 - I would go with an actual [powered converter box from a reliable vendor](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0047PDBP0) that has a friendly return policy should you not like the results.

Comment: the adaptor cost 1/2 the price of the apple tv ! maybe the netgear nas digital media center is a better alternative ?

Comment: Yes - if you haven't bought - why spend on a 1080p / all digital solution only to downsample things back to analog. Get a cheap belkin bluetooth receiver for $50 or a netgear cheapie if they fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I bought and AirPort Express, get the output in the input of my stereo, and publish music in the speaker.... work fine !

Comment: How does this relate to the Apple TV topic in the question?